# Cannot add element (set) into an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to add a set that satisfies some conditions into an arraylist, however it cannot be added.

```
public void insert(List<Set<Integer>> tran){
    Node left = new Node();
    Node right = new Node();
    List<Set<Integer>> insert_list = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
    for(int i = 0; i < insert_list.size(); i++){
        Set<Integer> temp = insert_list.get(i);
        System.out.println(temp);
        Iterator itr = temp.iterator();
        int value = (int)itr.next();
        System.out.println(value);
        if(value%2 ==0){
            left.leaf.add(temp);
        }
        else{
            right.leaf.add(temp);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(left.leaf);
    System.out.println(right.leaf);
```

In the main function, I called as:

```
Node test = new Node();
test.insert(candidate2);
```

This is a function under `Node` class, which its constructor looks like:

```
private List<Set<Integer>> leaf = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
private Node left; // the node that can point to the left
private Node right; // the node that can point to the right
public Node(){
    this.leaf = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
    left = null;
    right = null;
 }
```

Also, `System.out.println(value);` and `System.out.println(temp);` cannot be printed as well, which is really strange.

Moreover, if I change the iterator codes to `if((int)temp.toArray()[0]%2 == 0)`, it still does not work.

I have a `List<Set<Integer>> insert_list` with following attribute: `[[1, 15], [1, 58], [1, 274], [1, 326], [58, 15], [274, 15], [326, 15], [274, 58], [326, 58], [274, 326]]`. The desired output should be `[[274, 15], [326, 15], [274, 58],[326, 58], [274, 326]]` for the `left.leaf` and `[1, 15], [1, 58], [1, 274], [1, 326]]` for the `right.leaf`.

By the way, I tested these codes in the main function and it worked, I have totally no idea why it didn't work in this way.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

The output of my function is:

```
[]
[]
```

Comment: Show us some stack trace please...:)

Comment: @MordechayS There is no stack trace in my output. Everything is good except my output for ```left.leaf``` and ```right.leaf``` are just ```[]``` and ```[]```

Comment: is that a System.out.print output, or a debugger step-through one?

Comment: what he is asking is for have you ran the program.. what output does it show?

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama I just updated the result in the question! The result is just ```[] []```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the method arg - tran with your local var - insert_list.

What you intended to write is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tran.size(); i++){
    Set<Integer> temp = tran.get(i);
```

What do you need insert-list for? it seems redundant

Comment: At very beginning, I think every ```ArrayList``` as parameter should be initialized...It turns out I was wrong.